# What rules does Mongo Bson driver use to automap a type?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

When I call this:

`BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyType>();`

Under the covers the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/350adc845eae5bf3c4524788d11626c795d7c3e4/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/BsonClassMap.cs) calls this:

`return RegisterClassMap<TClass>(cm => { cm.AutoMap(); });`

And then it's off to mapping land.

I'm trying to figure out what rules are used when reflecting over the type to decide which fields and properties should be serialized/included in the map.

I've tried to reason-thru it by reading the code.  I thought someone with more knowledge here could shortcut a full walk-thru in the debugger.

I'd specifically like to know the individual rules used to make a yes/no decision on a type member and the order in which those rules are applied.

Comment: Had a browse around the docs and found this http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/ it doesn't seem to expand on what the default conventions it adheres to are though

Comment: The [`DefaultConventionPack`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/350adc845eae5bf3c4524788d11626c795d7c3e4/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Conventions/DefaultConventionPack.cs#L37) might be a good place to start.

Comment: David, Kirk - thanks for the links.  Because of the layers involved, I'm hoping someone already had the need to flatten-it-out just to be able to reason-thru the ruleset.